# Adding Elastic IP to ec2 instance using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is where anyway I could attach elastic ip from my cloudformation template?

```
{
"Description" : "Staging single instance",
"Outputs": {
    "InstanceID": {
        "Description": "The WWW instance id",
        "Value": { "Ref": "StageInstance" }
    }
},
"Parameters": {
    "AMI": {
        "Description": "The Amazon Ubuntu AMI",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "ami-009110a2bf8d7dd0a"
    },
    "EBSVolumeSize": {
        "Description": "The size of the EBS volume for the transcoder",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "20"
    },
    "InstanceType": {
        "AllowedValues": [
            "t2.micro",
            "t2.small",
            "t2.medium",
            "t2.large",
            "c4.large",
            "c4.xlarge",
            "c4.2xlarge",
            "c4.4xlarge",
            "c4.8xlarge",
            "t3.medium"
        ],
        "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type",
        "Default": "t2.micro",
        "Description": "EC2 instance type",
        "Type": "String"
    },
    "KeyName": {
        "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to NAT instances.",
                    "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
                    "ConstraintDescription" : "Must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."        }

},
"Resources": {
     "InstanceProfile" : {
         "Type" : "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
                "Properties" : {
                        "Path" : "/",
                                "Roles" : ["Ec2CloudDeploy"]
                                        }
                                            },
    "StageSecurityGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "GroupDescription": "Allow SSH, HTTP, and HTTPS access",
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "22",
                    "ToPort": "22",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                },
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "80",
                    "ToPort": "80",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                },
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "443",
                    "ToPort": "443",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
 "StageInstance": {
        "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",

        "Properties": {
            "SecurityGroupIds": [{"Ref": "StageSecurityGroup"}],
            "KeyName": {"Ref": "KeyName" },
            "ImageId": {"Ref": "AMI"},
            "InstanceType": {"Ref": "InstanceType"},
            "IamInstanceProfile" : {"Ref" : "InstanceProfile"},
            "Tags": [
                {"Key" : "Staging", "Value" : "Staging"}
            ]

 }
  }
 }
}
```

Is there any configuration which I can add to attach the elastic ip to the instance which would be launched by this instance.I know I can attach it using cli command buT i would like to add it through my cloudformation template.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Associate an existing Elastic IP with an Ec2 Instance from inside a CloudFormation script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755424/associate-an-existing-elastic-ip-with-an-ec2-instance-from-inside-a-cloudformati)

Answer (score 3):

Sure. as documented in [AWS::EC2::EIP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip.html):

> Specifies an Elastic IP (EIP) address and can, optionally, associate it with an Amazon EC2 instance.

By setting `InstanceId`, you associate the EIP to your CloudFormation's EC2 instance.

For your case this snippet should do the trick:

```
"Resources": {
    ...,
    "ElasticIP": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::EIP",
        "Properties": {
            "InstanceId": {"Ref" : "StageInstance"}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use [AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip-association.html):

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation",
  "Properties" : {
      "AllocationId" : String,
      "EIP" : String,
      "InstanceId" : String,
      "NetworkInterfaceId" : String,
      "PrivateIpAddress" : String
    }
}
```